# How to apply animation to vertically centered element with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a div within another div to which I would like to apply a CSS animation. The problem seems to be that I am applying multiple transforms to the div. In order to center the inner div, I am using the following:

```
#inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I then add the following class to the div on click:

```
.spin {
    animation: whirl 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes whirl {
    50% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

It seems that the fact that I have already used a `transform` to center the div makes it so that the animation doesn't work correctly. If I remove the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` line from the CSS, the animation works correctly, but the div is not centered.

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfojdsvr/2/) I made to demonstrate the issue.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `translate` is lost on `animation`.change it by adding both translate and rotate on animation

```
@keyframes whirl {
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```js
function spin() {
  $("#inner").addClass("spin");
}
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

#inner {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.spin {
  animation: whirl 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes whirl {
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="inner" onclick="spin()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense. And that seems to work.

Comment: @MalcolmG please upvote /accept the answer if its helpful

Comment: Will do. It's telling me I have 2 more minutes until I can accept the answer.